# R - conditional row subtraction

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, operation

I have the following data frames:

```
a <- structure(list(half.fac = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2006-08-29 05:00:00", 
"2006-08-29 05:30:00", "2006-08-29 06:00:00", "2006-08-29 06:30:00", 
"2006-08-29 07:00:00", "2006-08-29 07:30:00", "2006-08-29 08:00:00", 
"2006-08-29 08:30:00", "2006-08-29 09:00:00", "2006-08-29 09:30:00", 
"2006-08-29 10:00:00", "2006-08-29 10:30:00", "2006-08-29 11:00:00", 
"2006-08-29 11:30:00", "2006-08-29 12:00:00", "2006-08-29 12:30:00", 
"2006-08-29 13:00:00", "2006-08-29 13:30:00", "2006-08-29 14:00:00", 
"2006-08-29 14:30:00", "2006-08-29 15:00:00", "2006-08-29 15:30:00", 
"2006-08-29 16:00:00", "2006-08-29 16:30:00", "2006-08-29 17:00:00", 
"2006-08-29 17:30:00", "2006-08-29 18:00:00", "2006-08-29 18:30:00", 
"2006-08-29 19:00:00", "2006-08-29 19:30:00", "2006-08-29 20:00:00", 
"2006-08-29 20:30:00", "2006-08-29 21:00:00", "2006-08-29 21:30:00", 
"2006-08-29 22:00:00", "2006-08-29 22:30:00", "2006-08-29 23:00:00", 
"2006-08-29 23:30:00", "2006-08-30 00:00:00", "2006-08-30 00:30:00", 
"2006-08-30 01:00:00", "2006-08-30 01:30:00", "2006-08-30 02:00:00", 
"2006-08-30 02:30:00", "2006-08-30 03:00:00", "2006-08-30 03:30:00", 
"2006-08-30 04:00:00", "2006-08-30 04:30:00", "2006-08-30 05:00:00"
), class = "factor"), Ux = c(0.354, 0.38225, 0.48725, 0.43425, 
0.3825, 0.406, 0.45125, 0.5975, 0.62525, 0.587, 0.57925, 0.57125, 
0.52725, 0.4245, 0.37775, 0.4355, 0.4585, 0.3125, 0.4075, 0.17275
), Ts = c(16.0024, 16.2281, 16.2468, 16.0788, 16.0465, 15.8956, 
15.8922, 15.9074, 15.7582, 15.7938, 15.8565, 15.6904, 15.6073, 
15.6632, 15.6344, 15.6531, 15.7006, 15.6989, 15.6938, 15.3022
)), .Names = c("half.fac", "Ux", "Ts"), row.names = c(NA, 20L
), class = "data.frame")
```

and

```
b <- structure(list(half.fac = structure(1:49, .Label = c("2006-08-29 05:00:00", 
"2006-08-29 05:30:00", "2006-08-29 06:00:00", "2006-08-29 06:30:00", 
"2006-08-29 07:00:00", "2006-08-29 07:30:00", "2006-08-29 08:00:00", 
"2006-08-29 08:30:00", "2006-08-29 09:00:00", "2006-08-29 09:30:00", 
"2006-08-29 10:00:00", "2006-08-29 10:30:00", "2006-08-29 11:00:00", 
"2006-08-29 11:30:00", "2006-08-29 12:00:00", "2006-08-29 12:30:00", 
"2006-08-29 13:00:00", "2006-08-29 13:30:00", "2006-08-29 14:00:00", 
"2006-08-29 14:30:00", "2006-08-29 15:00:00", "2006-08-29 15:30:00", 
"2006-08-29 16:00:00", "2006-08-29 16:30:00", "2006-08-29 17:00:00", 
"2006-08-29 17:30:00", "2006-08-29 18:00:00", "2006-08-29 18:30:00", 
"2006-08-29 19:00:00", "2006-08-29 19:30:00", "2006-08-29 20:00:00", 
"2006-08-29 20:30:00", "2006-08-29 21:00:00", "2006-08-29 21:30:00", 
"2006-08-29 22:00:00", "2006-08-29 22:30:00", "2006-08-29 23:00:00", 
"2006-08-29 23:30:00", "2006-08-30 00:00:00", "2006-08-30 00:30:00", 
"2006-08-30 01:00:00", "2006-08-30 01:30:00", "2006-08-30 02:00:00", 
"2006-08-30 02:30:00", "2006-08-30 03:00:00", "2006-08-30 03:30:00", 
"2006-08-30 04:00:00", "2006-08-30 04:30:00", "2006-08-30 05:00:00"
), class = "factor"), Ux = c(0.386129423856881, 0.376585152777778, 
0.223084, 0.324716694444444, 0.284751444444444, 0.330879361111111, 
0.435775208333333, 0.615431625, 0.0626402222222222, 0.294361277777778, 
0.464928125, 0.194410652777778, 0.162782402777778, 0.452202958333333, 
0.115627805555556, -0.504861722222222, -0.519877875, -0.472751402777778, 
-0.304711708333333, -0.422057305555556, -0.366469180555556, -0.733386694444444, 
-0.547648027777778, -0.755199347222222, -0.550659486111111, -0.5423535, 
-0.366822472222222, -0.383240513888889, -0.310595805555556, -0.52455025, 
-0.362563625, -0.652825569444444, -0.610772416666667, -0.410371666666667, 
-0.472121152777778, -0.425157875, -0.402904430555556, -0.500900541666667, 
-0.212771525026505, -0.311444125, -0.283801236111111, -0.329137972222222, 
0.0119679583333333, -0.0432450416666667, -0.116798097222222, 
-0.0186036944444444, 0.18647825, 0.0159295694444444, 0.2725), 
    Ts = c(15.6259581698983, 15.2544032611111, 15.3477244944444, 
    16.0545841722222, 16.8355633888889, 17.7415598722222, 18.6617318333333, 
    19.5413804333333, 20.3955452333333, 21.3235478222222, 22.1279614944444, 
    23.0201452888889, 23.5360555222222, 24.1431266555556, 24.6397015777778, 
    24.9368367833333, 24.8767400111111, 25.0295079222222, 24.9217255611111, 
    24.7817519388889, 25.0392368777778, 24.8607259111111, 24.6273860888889, 
    23.9305384555556, 23.6246723388889, 23.3412936666667, 22.5086166611111, 
    21.3677308722222, 20.4862971111111, 19.9382697666667, 19.1141656277778, 
    18.9857482722222, 18.6177629666667, 18.06932875, 17.7128214, 
    17.2961282944444, 16.8209205833333, 16.9382630722222, 16.2425613023827, 
    16.31353845, 16.2208566277778, 16.0621524611111, 15.3475440055556, 
    14.9305123722222, 14.3440030833333, 13.6119074444444, 13.3696283111111, 
    13.4342943555556, 13.2741)), .Names = c("half.fac", "Ux.30min", 
"Ts.30min"), row.names = c(NA, -49L), class = "data.frame")
```

where a is my high-frequency measurement for one entire day and b is its average for each half hour.

What I need to do is, for each row, subtract b$Ux.30min from a$Ux IF and only IF the half-hourly fractions are the same (a$half.fac = b$half.fac). And do the same for Ts too.

What I have in mind is something like:

```
if a$half.fac = b$half.fac then 

   a$Ts.diff <- a$Ts - b$Ts.30min 
   a$Ux.diff <- a$Ux - b$Ux.30min 

endif
```

To someone who might be familiar with this, I am trying to perform a Reynolds decomposition on the data.

Regardless of the method/package, ideally it should be as efficient (fast) as possible, because in reality my data frame 'a' is almost one million lines long!

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a similar approach using `dplyr`. The first step is to merge your `a` and `b`. Then, you do the calculation and create new columns.

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(a, b) %>%
    mutate(Ux.Ux30 = Ux - Ux.30min,
           Ts.Ts30 = Ts - Ts.30min)

# A part of the results
#              half.fac      Ux      Ts  Ux.30min Ts.30min      Ux.Ux30     Ts.Ts30
#1  2006-08-29 05:00:00 0.35400 16.0024 0.3861294 15.62596 -0.032129424  0.37644183
#2  2006-08-29 05:00:00 0.38225 16.2281 0.3861294 15.62596 -0.003879424  0.60214183
#3  2006-08-29 05:00:00 0.48725 16.2468 0.3861294 15.62596  0.101120576  0.62084183
#4  2006-08-29 05:00:00 0.43425 16.0788 0.3861294 15.62596  0.048120576  0.45284183
#5  2006-08-29 05:00:00 0.38250 16.0465 0.3861294 15.62596 -0.003629424  0.42054183
```

**EXTRA**

Here is one way to use data.table. This is my naive attempt.

```
#Convert data.frame to data.table
setDT(a)
setDT(b)

# Set a key column for merging a and b
setkey(a, "half.fac")
setkey(b, "half.fac")

# Merge a and b, and do the calculation
b[a][, `:=`(Ux.Ux30 = Ux - Ux.30min, Ts.Ts30 = Ts - Ts.30min)]
```

Comment: This solution is really fast! Thanks!

Comment: Pleasure. If you use `data.table` it will be even faster.

Comment: Willing to provide an example?

Comment: @ThiagoV.dosSantos I added a sample for you. There will be better ways of doing this in data.table. Have a look of SO questions. :)

Answer (score 1):

First merge a and b:

```
 ab <- merge(a, b, by=1)
 ab$Ts.diff <- ab$Ts - ab$Ts.30min 
 ab$Ux.diff <- ab$Ux - bb$Ux.30min
```

With the example given:

```
> ab$Ts.diff <- ab$Ts - ab$Ts.30min 
>      ab$Ux.diff <- ab$Ux - ab$Ux.30min
> ab
              half.fac      Ux      Ts  Ux.30min Ts.30min     Ts.diff
1  2006-08-29 05:00:00 0.35400 16.0024 0.3861294 15.62596  0.37644183
2  2006-08-29 05:00:00 0.38225 16.2281 0.3861294 15.62596  0.60214183
3  2006-08-29 05:00:00 0.48725 16.2468 0.3861294 15.62596  0.62084183
4  2006-08-29 05:00:00 0.43425 16.0788 0.3861294 15.62596  0.45284183
5  2006-08-29 05:00:00 0.38250 16.0465 0.3861294 15.62596  0.42054183
6  2006-08-29 05:00:00 0.40600 15.8956 0.3861294 15.62596  0.26964183
7  2006-08-29 05:00:00 0.45125 15.8922 0.3861294 15.62596  0.26624183
8  2006-08-29 05:00:00 0.59750 15.9074 0.3861294 15.62596  0.28144183
9  2006-08-29 05:00:00 0.62525 15.7582 0.3861294 15.62596  0.13224183
10 2006-08-29 05:00:00 0.58700 15.7938 0.3861294 15.62596  0.16784183
11 2006-08-29 05:00:00 0.57925 15.8565 0.3861294 15.62596  0.23054183
12 2006-08-29 05:00:00 0.57125 15.6904 0.3861294 15.62596  0.06444183
13 2006-08-29 05:00:00 0.52725 15.6073 0.3861294 15.62596 -0.01865817
14 2006-08-29 05:00:00 0.42450 15.6632 0.3861294 15.62596  0.03724183
15 2006-08-29 05:00:00 0.37775 15.6344 0.3861294 15.62596  0.00844183
16 2006-08-29 05:00:00 0.43550 15.6531 0.3861294 15.62596  0.02714183
17 2006-08-29 05:00:00 0.45850 15.7006 0.3861294 15.62596  0.07464183
18 2006-08-29 05:00:00 0.31250 15.6989 0.3861294 15.62596  0.07294183
19 2006-08-29 05:00:00 0.40750 15.6938 0.3861294 15.62596  0.06784183
20 2006-08-29 05:00:00 0.17275 15.3022 0.3861294 15.62596 -0.32375817
        Ux.diff
1  -0.032129424
2  -0.003879424
3   0.101120576
4   0.048120576
5  -0.003629424
6   0.019870576
7   0.065120576
8   0.211370576
9   0.239120576
10  0.200870576
11  0.193120576
12  0.185120576
13  0.141120576
14  0.038370576
15 -0.008379424
16  0.049370576
17  0.072370576
18 -0.073629424
19  0.021370576
20 -0.213379424
```